# karate masking sensitive headers in HTML report

Tags: karate

I am using karate DSL for API tests and want to mask some headers E.g:- Authorization, session_cookie, etc with sensitive info in the HTML report generated at the end of execution. I have added below in the config as mentioned in documentation.

```
var LM = Java.type('demo.headers.LogModifier');
karate.configure('logModifier', LM.INSTANCE);
```

In the LogModifier.java file under demo/headers location of the project, I am adding the contents of https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/DemoLogModifier.java with the below changes-

```
public String header(String header, String value) {
    if (header.toLowerCase().contains("authorization")) {
        return "***";
    }
    return value;
}
```

But this is not resulting in the Authorization header getting masked.

I have gone through previous questions on stack overflow but still facing the issue. Could someone please help in resolving this issue?

Comment: speaking for myself, I can't help unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas , have logged https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2346.